# How to add additional header for cordova web view requests

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm using the Apache Cordova WebView. In the html I use img tags. For the HTTP requests of this images I would like to add a referer in the HTTP header.

I tried to use a own CordovaWebViewClient and intercepting with overriding shouldInterceptRequest or shouldOverrideUrlLoading:

```java
public class CustomCordovaWebViewClient extends CordovaWebViewClient {

    public CustomCordovaWebViewClient(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView view) {
        super(cordova, view);
    }

    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {

        Log.d("DEBUG", "AAAAAAAAAA Should intercept request" + url);
        //Implement your code
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "AAAAAAAAAA onLoadResource" +url);
        //Implement your code
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }



    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "AAAAAAAAAA On page finished "+url);
        //Implement your code
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        Log.d("DEBUG", "AAAAAAAAAA should override url loading "+url);
        //Implement your code
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);


    }
}
```

The CustomCordovaWebViewClient I register by following code:

```java
cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
cwv.setWebViewClient(new CustomCordovaWebViewClient(getTabActivity(), cwv));
cwv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

No function will be called on any request.

Is there a better solution for adding http header?

The solution with loadUrl(url, extraHeaders) doesn't work with cordova.

I'm using Cordova 3.6.3

Comment: Did you found a solution for that?